# C# StreamWriter writing over a current text file

Tags: c#, .net

I have a text file with the following text inside:

```
[username][0]
```

I have opened the file using StreamWriter and I want to change the `0` to a `1` using the `StreamWriter.Write` Method. How can I do this?

Comment: It is somewhat painful to change one character in the middle of the stream with `StreamWriter`, especially if you only can use `.Write`... Is overwriting whole file an option?

Comment: Does it have to be done with a `StreamWriter`? Use `FileStream` find the text, write on that position, then close the stream.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, you can do both.  A `StreamWriter` does write to a `Stream` after all, and a `FileStream` by default.  You can even create a `StreamReader` on top of the same `FileStream` to find the correct position.

Comment: I have used Streamwriter.BaseSteam.Position to set the position overwrite the "0". I know where the 0 is,and it will always be in the same place every time. Is this a good practise?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact byte position of the character(s) you want to overwrite then you can do something like this:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
{
    writer.BaseStream.Seek(bytePos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    writer.Write('1');
}
```

If you don't know the exact byte position then you could do something like this:

```
using (var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
{
    var openBracketCount = 0;

    // Keep reading characters until the second open bracket is found.
    do
    {
        var ch = Convert.ToChar(reader.Read());

        if (ch == '[')
        {
            openBracketCount++;
        }
    } while (openBracketCount < 2);

    writer.Write('1');
}
```